# Dynamic HTML Spread sheet, Substring(), how do I grab a specfic value?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the situition, which actually relates to a earlier question.
I have created a spread sheet that will be populated with values by the users input. Once those values are input I need to be able to grab the the coordinates that the user will enter into a text box in order to add those values. The formula that some one will enter is limited for this example to a simple =SUM(1,1,2,1). So that being said here's what I've gotten so far

```
function calculate() {
    var row1;
    var row2;
    var col1;
    var col2;

    var row = document.getElementById("row");
    var col = document.getElementById("col");
    var value = document.getElementById(row + "_" + col);
    var formula = document.getElementById("inputText");

    formula = formula.value; //=SUM(1,2,2,1)
    formula1 = formula;

    row = row.value;
    col = col.value;

    col1 = formula1.substr(5, 5); //row 1
    col2 = formula1.substr(6, 8); //column 1
    row1 = formula1.substr(7, 10); //row 2
    row2 = formula1.substr(10, 12); // column2
}
```

From here I'd use the coordinates extracted from inputted field to determine the cell values, and from there add them together and either overwrite or enter it into a new cell.

So basically I'm hitting a road block trying to understand how to grab the int values in order to have them as usable as coordinates.  I think I'm on the right route, but him hitting a road block.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're sure your coordinates are only ever going to be 0-9, you might want to rethink your parsing algorithm.

To your question, how to convert a string into an integer in Javascript, try this:

```
formula1 = "=SUM(1,2,2,1)";   
col1 = parseInt(formula1.substr(5, 1));

alert(typeof(col1)); // Type is now number, not string
alert(col1); // So you can see the value... 1
```